# mod_rewrite: 2 same conditions that works properly

Tags: variables, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

good day everyone!

is it possible to have a mod rewrite like this?

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    $1.php?param1=$2 [L]
```

that is exactly the same with

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$   $1.php?param=$2 [L]
```

i already tried this two in the same htaccess but the system only reads the first one.
what i want to do is i can display the both params at the same time using

```
<?php
echo $_GET[param1];
echo $_GET[param];
?>
```

thanks in advance and more power!

Answer (score 0):

You can get both like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    $1/$2?param1=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$   $1.php?param=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The other thing is your second grouping in your second rule won't match a trailing slash because `([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)` is greedy and will gobble up a trailing slash. You can make it ungreedy by adding a `?`: `([A-Za-z0-9-/]+?)`